# cannot find symbol method getMap()

Tags: android

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

I start an activity from MainActivity alike:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_car) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, Map_Activity.class);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

and all work fine until I get ( Error:(222, 97) error: cannot find symbol method getMap() here:

```
private void setUpMap() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);

    }
}
```

Please help me to step this problem!

Comment: it is because there is no `getMap`. Have a look to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
```

`getMap()` is deprecated, use `getMapAsync()`

Comment: It would be nice to provide some explanation on why this should be done like this.

Answer (score 4):

use `getMapAsync()` of `SupportMapFragment`

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap  = googleMap;
        }
    });
```

you can find document [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))

Comment: mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this); return Error:(223, 109) error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to GoogleMap

Comment: post your xml also in question

Answer (score 0):

Implementation for Google Maps is changed now. You need to use [getMapAsync](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) (OnMapReadyCallback callback)

This new [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) will help you getting started.

Comment: Error:(223, 109) error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to GoogleMap

Comment: Follow the tutorial properly, you need to assign map on when onMapReady function is called.